# Not able to connect to mysql running in a Docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I am not able to connect to mysql using a JAVA Program.

sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 3306

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13226/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      13232/docker-proxy

Even with telnet i tested it was connecting
telnet localhost 3306

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'

But My java application not able to connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
```